# Reading files to list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, file

When you use the fileName.readlines() function in Python, is there a symbol for the end of the file that is included in the list?

For example, if the file is read into a list of strings and the last line is 'End', will there be another place in the list with a symbol indicating the end of the file?

Thanks.

Comment: how is it hard to test yourself?

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and check how lists work in python in the first place. There is absolutely no need for a list to contain an item indicating you are at its end.

Answer (score 5):

No, the list contains one element for each line in the file.

You can do something with each line in a for look like this:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    # Do something with this line
    process(line)
```

Python has a shorter way of accomplishing this that avoids reading the whole file into memory at once

```
for line in infile:
    # Do something with this line
    process(line)
```

If you just want the last line of the file

```
lines = infile.readlines()
last_line = lines[-1]
```

Why do you think you need a special symbol at the end?

Answer (score 1):

The list returned by `.readlines()`, like any other Python list, has no "end" marker -- assumin e.g. you start with `L = myfile.readlines()`, you can see how many items `L` has with `len(L)`, get the last one with `L[-1]`, loop over all items one after the other with `for item in L:`, and so forth ... again -- just like any other list.

If for some peculiar reason you want, after the last line, some special "sentinel" value, you could for example do `L.append('')` to add just such a sentinel, or marker -- the empty string is never going to be the value of any other line (since each item is a complete line including the trailing `'\n'`, so it will never be an empty string!).

You could use other arbitrary markers, such as `None`, but often it's simpler, when feasible [[and it's obviously feasible in this case, as I've just shown]], if the sentinel is of exactly the same type as any other item.  That depends on what processing you're doing that needs a past-the-end "sentinel" (I'm not going to guess because you give us no indication, and only relatively rare problems are best solved that way in Python, anyway;-), but in almost every conceivable case of sentinel use a `''` sentinel will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It simply returns a list containing each line -- there's no "EOF" item in the list.